# Command docker-compose up gets stuck

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, jboss, macos-ventura

I'm currently working in a custom project involving Docker and Jboss. The first 2/3 times that I run the command `docker-compose up`, the log gets stuck in different part of the build. After those 2/3 attempts, the command works correctly. I'm working on a MacBook Pro 2021 with macOS Ventura 13.0.

The docker-compose file is the following:

```
version: '2'

services:
  webapp:
    environment:
      - SCRIPT_DEBUG=false
      - DEBUG=${WEBAPP}   
    image:
        "${REGISTRY}/ispdev/jboss:743GA-jdk1.8-V2"
    ports: 
      - "${WEBAPP_PORT}:8080"
      - "${WEBAPP_DEBUG_PORT}:8787"
    volumes: 
      - "${WS_ROOT_DIR}/${APPL_ROOT}/${WEBAPP_EAR_DIR}/${WEBAPP_FINAL_ARTIFACT}:/opt/eap/standalone/deployments/${WEBAPP_FINAL_ARTIFACT}"
      - "${WS_ROOT_DIR}/${COMPOSE_ROOT}/resources/jboss.yml:/usr/local/y2j/jboss.yml"
```

I've just tried to run several times `docker-compose up`

Comment: how about adding `docker-compose` file so we can try to help ? and please whenever you have time, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask good StackOverflow question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the few information, but I thought that since the project is a custom one, the docker-compose file was not so important. I have edited the question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try to use this command line 
" docker system prune -f ; docker volume prune -f ;docker rm -f -v $(docker ps -q -a) "

Answer (score 0):

What version do you have of docker? `docker -v`

You may have to reinstall docker. Here is a link

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

Comment: And did you use docker-desktop or homebrew installed docker

Comment: I have installed Docker with the docker-desktop dmg. My docker version is the 20.10.20, do you think that's better to install docker with brew?

Comment: you can try to reinstall docker-compose with brew